# Material UI datagrid datetime

Tags: reactjs, datetime, material-ui, datagrid

I have two questions regarding the Material UI - datagrid filter with type:dateTime.

1. When selecting the date in the filter, it shows the AM/PM date format. I did not find anyway to change the localformat.

[DatePicker in filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDUER.png)

2. I use server side filtering and when the filterModel is sent to the server, the dateTime format is "2022-08-05T21:30". Any way to change this format as well without creating a custom filter model?

Thanks for any tipps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are wanting to filter over date without time stamps (server side and client side)
If so, that particular column should be defined as the date type instead of dateTime...

```
const columns = [

    {
         field: 'date',
         headerName: 'Date',
         width: 140,  
         type: 'date',
    }
];
```